50MM 1.8 Lense will not longer focus using Alston adapter
I have had the Alston Mount Adapter CEF-SE for a year. I recently started experiencing manual and autofocus issues when using any of my Canon lenses.
At first, it would allow me to focus or attempt to focus in AF mode manually, but now it does nothing.
Both lenses work fine on my canon body but not with my Sony. The lenses were working with the adapter in the past but now nothing is happening. ☹️
Has anyone else experienced an issue like this? If so, were you able to fix it.

What does "in AF mode manually" mean?

Did anything change about your Sony camera recently? I believe there was a significant firmware update from Sony recently - did you install it?

Possibly dirt/oxidation on contacts on the adapter, try cleaning in them on both sides. Is there a lens working on the Sony?

Which EF 50mm f/1.8 lens? The newer EF 50mm f/1.8 STM uses an entirely different technology to AF and to manually focus-by-wire than the older EF 50mm f/1.8 and EF 50mm f/1.8 II.
